# Creating new variable from another

Tags: javascript, variables

What would be the best way to create a new array or object from another. Since doing

```
 var oldvar = {x:1,y:2} //or [x,y]
 var newvar = oldvar
```

will link them, what would be the bets best way to clone or cope the new variable?

Comment: i'm pretty sure that doesn't actually link the variables.

Comment: Why do you think they're linked? What brought you to that conclusion? Is this your actual example, or are you actually using an Object but decided to post a question using a number?

Comment: That would be true for reference type vars, but that's value type.

Comment: I was mistaken about the type, I happens only in arrays and objects

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Numbers in JavaScript

Numbers in JavaScript are what the spec calls ['**Primitive Value Type**'](http://es5.github.io/#x4.3.2)

From the [specification about Numbers](http://es5.github.io/#x4.3.19):

> Number value # Ⓣ
>   primitive value corresponding to a double-precision 64-bit binary format IEEE 754 value.
>
> NOTE A Number value is a member of the Number type and is a direct representation of a number.

So in your case `newvar` will be a *copy* of oldvar and not a reference.

In JavaScript, `Number`, `Boolean`, `undefined`, `null` or `String` are value types.
When passing any of these 5 around, you are in fact passing *values* and not references, no need to clone those.

When you pass anything else around (Objects) *need* to use cloning since they are *reference* types.

When cloning objects in JavaScript there are two approaches.

#### Shallow Cloning

This means you clone 1 level deep. Assuming all our properties in the object are enumerable (This is usually the case if you haven't used property descriptors) you can use something like:

```
var a = {a:3,b:5}; 
var copy = {};
for(var prop in a){ 
 copy[prop] = a[prop];
}
```

However, often we want to copy the object's own properties and not everything it might inherit from its prototype, so we can do:

```
var copy = {};
for(var prop in a){
  if(a.hasOwnProperty(prop)){//check that the cloned property belongs to _a_ itself
     copy[prop] = a[prop];
  }
}
```

Note these two only shallow copy properties off `a`, they do not deal with setting the prototype, and clone all the properties by reference (Except properties who are primitive value types themselves :) ).

#### Deep copying

Deep copying means creating a clone of the object that is several levels deep. This calls to *recursion* since deep copying is defined as such (in psuedocode)

```
CopyObject(object)
    If object is a primitive value type
       return object
    clone := Empty Object
    For every member of object 
        Add CopyObject(member) as a property to clone 
    Return clone
```

We are applying the algorithm recursively on object properties of the clone.

Here is a sample implementation that I documented for you. It assumes ES5 (Chrome) but you can easily adapt it to other/older browsers. It does more stuff like treat `Date` and `Regex` like special cases. It also keeps a dictionary of properties it already handled so it will be able to handle circular references in an object. It is intended for learning and not for production use :) If you have any questions about it feel free.

```
var clone = function (a) {
    var passedRefs = [];     // Keep track of references you passed to avoid cycles
    var passedRefCreated = [];
    function clone2(a1) { // Inner function to handle the actual cloning
        var obj;
        if (typeof a1 !== "object" || a1 === null) { // Handle value type
            return a1;
        }
        var locInpPassed = passedRefs.indexOf(a1); // Detect circular reference
        if (locInpPassed !== -1) {
            return passedRefCreated[locInpPassed];
        }
        passedRefs.push(a1); // Add the object to the references to avoid circular references later
        if (a1 instanceof Date) { // Handle date and RegExp for special cases
            obj = new Date(a1.getTime());
        } else if (a1 instanceof RegExp) {
            obj = new RegExp(a1);
        }else if (Array.isArray(a1)){// handle arrays in order for Array.isArray to work. Thanks FizzyTea for catching this.
            obj = [];
        } else { // Create a new object with the prototype of the one we're cloning to support prototypical inheritance. Prototypes are _shared_
            obj = Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(a1));
        }
        passedRefCreated[passedRefs.indexOf(a1)] = obj; // Add to the references created dict
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a1).forEach(function (prop) { // Go through all the property, even the ones that are not enumerable
            obj[prop] = clone2(a1[prop]); // Call the algorithm recursively, just like in the pseudo code above
        });
        return obj;
    }
    return clone2(a); // Call the inner function that has access to the dictionary 
}
```

(For example, you can use a [`for... in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop to iterate through the properties).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote 2 relation functions for deep copying arrays and objects in javascript:

```
function clone_object(o) {
    var r = {};
    for (var p in o) {
        if (o[p].constructor == Array) {
            r[p] = clone_array(o[p]);
        } else if (o[p].constructor ==  Object) {
            r[p] = arguments.callee(o[p]);
        } else {
            r[p] = o[p];
        }
    }
    return r;
}

function clone_array(o) {
    var r = [];
    for (var p = 0, l = o.length; p < l; p++) {
        if (o[p].constructor == Array) {
            r[p] = arguments.callee(o[p]);
        } else if (o[p].constructor ==  Object) {
            r[p] = clone_object(o[p]);
        } else {
            r[p] = o[p];
        }
    }
    return r;
}
```

Example:

```
var o = { name: 'Prototype', version: 1.5, authors: ['sam', 'contributors'] };
var o2 = clone_object(o);
o2.authors.pop();

alert(o.authors);
// -> ['sam', 'contributors']

alert(o2.authors);
// -> ['sam']
```